# Not able to figure out how to use dagger in my app. Seems to be the case of circular dependency

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Following is the dependency graph of my app. GameView constructor looks as follows

```
class GameView (
    private var gameActivity: GameActivity,
    private val screenWidth: Int,
    private val screenHeight: Int
) : SurfaceView(gameActivity), Runnable {
}
```

GameView constructor takes GameActivity instance as a parameter. Is this the case of circular dependency? Because GameActivity's dependency is GameView and GameView's dependency is also GameActivity. How to resolve these kind of circular dependencies. Can somebody please share the code to Handle this kind of scenario.
[image]
In the above dependency graph, if i want to pass GameView instance to ShooterPlane, this will cause the dependency cycle. How to avoid such dependency cycles ?
source code link
https://github.com/kpradeepkumarreddy/DaggerBirdShooter

Answer (score 0):

If you have circular dependency the only solutions i have found is to use
`Lazy<T>` in ShooterPlane [More information in dagger2 documentation](https://dagger.dev/dev-guide/#lazy-injections)
And after that us Lazy.get when you need GameView in shooterPlane

```java
class ShooterPlane(private val gameView: Lazy<GameView>) {
fun someMethod(){
    gameView.get().someMethodInGameView()
}
```

The inconvnient about this solution is that Injection directly impact parameter of you constructeur.
But it's work and i think their is some tips from avoiding this drawBack